# How to have Internet Explorer hold on to a stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am streaming a CSV file to Internet Explorer.  At the end of the streaming, Internet Explorer presents an Open, Save, and Cancel dialog.  If you wait 30 seconds after the dialog is presented and click the Open button, Internet Explorer does nothing.  This works fine in Firefox.  Do I need some other command besides Flush and End on the Response?  Here is the code that I have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = ReportService.GetAllOwnerAircraftPaymentInformation();

    //Generate the report
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        CsvHelper csvHelper = new CsvHelper();

        csvHelper.DataTableToCsv(writer, dt);

        writer.Flush();

        //Send it to the browser
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        string fileName = string.Format("MassAVRMSDataExport{0}.csv", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss"));

        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", stream.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        StreamHelper.CopyStream(stream, Response.OutputStream);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: after your first `Response.ContentTye` try adding this line `Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"` also you can add this line as well `Response.ContentType = "application/download"` after the line too.. try both lines ..

Comment: It seems Internet Explorer wanted a application/download content type.  That was the one that worked.  Thanks so much.

Comment: I will add that as the answer and you can accept it if you like thanks

Comment: FYI, everyone this only is happening for Internet Explorer 8.  Internet Explorer 9 does not have this problem.

Comment: Greg that's good info to know .. I never did like IE8 personally too many bugs ..have you ever thought about testing or trying to do the same thing with `JavaScript` or `JQuery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greg you need to add the following when working with IE Explorer

```
Response.ContentType = "application/download"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
stream.Position = 0;
StreamHelper.CopyStream(stream, Response.OutputStream);
```